# Get ObjectId from Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-core, claims, objectid

I need help in return a users ObjectId from Azure AD in my ASP.NET core application.
The following returns null:

```
        var identity = User.Identity as System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;
        var objectId = identity?.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier")?.Value;
```

I've also tried below as I have seen others mentioned it is mapped to the objectId:

`identity?.FindFirst(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;`

It returns a value but it is not the objectId as shown in Azure AD.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about a JWT token? If so, you want the `sub` claim from the token, `var subClaim = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` then access the string value through `subClaim.Value`. Don't go through `User.Identity` for the sub or object id.

Comment: Hi @jandrew, I was hoping you can get the ObjectId from the System.Security.Claims namespace?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you want the the user's object-id (Azure AD), you can get the claim directly from `User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);` which will give you the `Claim` object associated with it. You can get the value through `Claim.Value` which will be a string representation of the object-id.

Comment: Sorry if I misinterupted what I need, this should be what I am looking for. I will give it a go and get back to u.

Comment: did you figure out how to get the ObjectId? Or if you didn't need it after all?